# Canvas element covering the entire screen?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to use `<canvas>` in iPhone Safari, and if I place the element in the body, there are unused pixels to the left and top of the element. I tried specifying `margin:0;padding:0` with CSS to no avail.

What's going on here?

```
<html>
<head>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#screen').attr("height", $(window).height() );
            $('#screen').attr("width", $(window).width() );

            //prevent scrolling
            $(document).bind('touchstart touchmove', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id = "screen">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you stick "margin:0;padding:0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin`,`padding`, and `border` have no effect.

Use `position:absolute; top:0;left:0`

Comment: Unfortunately, `position:absolute; top:0;left:0` shoved the canvas on top of all content for me. No fiddling (z-index, etc.) was able to remedy it. Added an answer below for what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

add `<style>* {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%}</style>`